# How to perform authentication and authorization in microfrontend application using single SPA(Angular) with auth0

Tags: auth0, micro-frontend, single-spa-angular

I have created the microfrontend application using single SPA(Angular) and created two apps, angular1 and angular2. Now I need to perform a authentication and authorization using auth0. Can anyone suggest me the solution, and which is the best solution whether to implement authentication at the root level or each application level?